# Feeding uint8 type to NN

Tags: neural-network, keras, numpy

I’m facing some (RAM) memory issues to train a neural network.

I have an input array consisting of grayscale images encoded as the type numpy.uint8 (therefore the whole range 0-255 can be covered). When feeding the data to the network, I’m supposed to normalize the values into the 0-1 range, making them now floating points (numpy.float64 or 32). However, this conversion makes my data 8x(or 4x) bigger, which my RAM memory can’t handle.

Would there be a way I could overcome this issue?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you loading the entire dataset into memory all at once?  Could you instead stream the data from disk in batches?

Comment: @zachdj I’m not sure on how to do this. From all the code examples I looked into Keras documentation, the training array is loaded at once, and the batch size is configured by the model.fit function.

Comment: Instead of fit method, try fit_generator and generate images for every batch. Put an effort and I can tell u you will get rid of this RAM issues.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on data generators in Keras: https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

Answer (score 1):

After normalization, [cast](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast) the numbers to `float16` or `bfloat16`. Those are the smallest floats available in Keras.